# About container options of Azure Batch

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-batch

I am in trouble with the container options of Azure Batch.

To change the hostname of the container to be started, set `--hostname="test"` to the containerRunOptions of Task.

However, it is an error!
`ContainerSettings: --hostname="test" Message: create_container() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hostname '`

Even `-h test` will result in a similar error.
Other options work fine.(--volume etc...)

Pool Infomation:
Publisher:microsoft-azure-batch
OS:centos-container
sku:7-4
image:centos:latest(docker hub)

Is this a bug in Azure Batch?
Is the option to specify it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer (2018-08-23):**

The fix for this issue has been rolled out.

**Previous answer:**

This was identified as a service defect and will be addressed in a future version. You can track the [Azure Batch Node Agent release notes](https://github.com/Azure/Batch/blob/master/changelogs/nodeagent/CHANGELOG.md) for when the fix is released.

If you are using Batch to execute tasks without performing deeper integration, e.g., you are using the Azure CLI or similar tooling, you can use [Batch Shipyard](https://github.com/Azure/batch-shipyard) in "non-native mode" to work around this problem in the meantime. (Disclaimer: I'm a contributor for this code).